# How to remove buffer created in such way?

Tags: c++, c, memory, ffmpeg, buffer

So I create buffer like

```
unsigned char *pb_buffer;
```

I fill it with some ffmpeg data from some older din buffer

```
    int len = url_close_dyn_buf(pFormatContext -> pb, (unsigned char **)(&pb_buffer));
```

I do some stuff with that data

Now I want to delete that buffer of mine. ow to do such thing?

I tried   `free(&pb_buffer);` app dies... and brings me into some C++ doc I do not get...

I tried `delete[] pb_buffer;` os kills my app...

Comment: You didn't allocate any space for that buffer.  Either there's something you're not telling us or your program is horribly wrong (and probably segfaults).  Also, the `(unsigned char **)` cast is unnecessary.

Comment: what he isn't saying is that url_close_dyn_buf() allocates the buffer for the caller, and that it needs to be freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned char *pb_buffer` doesn't create a buffer, it creates a pointer, which initially isn't pointing to anything. It's the call to `url_close_dyn_buf` that allocates the buffer, and stores a pointer to it in the place specified by its second argument.

The documentation for `url_close_dyn_buf` should tell you how to free it. The documentation is a bit sketchy, but `av_free(pb_buffer)` is the answer. The documentation for `av_free` recommends using `av_freep(&pb_buffer)` instead: that does the same thing and then sets `pb_buffer` to 0.

Comment: funny thing is - it did not reduced mem leak=(

Comment: @Kabumbus: how are you measuring/defining "memory leak"? If it's with a proper leak detection tool (valgrind etc), is it still reporting the same number of leaked allocations? If it's with `ps` or task manager then note that freeing memory doesn't in general return it to the OS - your process will hang on to it, so it can use it for other things.

Answer (score 3):

av_free(pb_buffer) perhaps? The function appears to be internal to ffmpeg, and its documentation indicates that you need to use av_free() to free the buffer it allocates.

[The function is documented here.](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_8h.html#3b6a91097ad4f63c0e6ddc3301f18688)

Comment: looks like it: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_8h.html#3b6a91097ad4f63c0e6ddc3301f18688